# Flutter project unable to sync with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, flutter

I'm new to android studio and have been working on a small project, however after i changed my pc I tried to copy everything i did before and then follow the steps as before. However when creating the android project in firebase, the app doesn't seem to sync with it. Here's what I get after running the project :

```
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"c5f91b7c-12f5-4bf7-9a15-65269a624386","id":"0","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
[+3055 ms] calculateSha: LocalDirectory: '/home/shr/AndroidStudioProjects/eco/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk'/app.apk
[  +54 ms] calculateSha: reading file took 53us
[ +644 ms] calculateSha: computing sha took 643us
[   +5 ms] ✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
[   +3 ms] executing: /home/shr/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.2/aapt dump xmltree /home/shr/AndroidStudioProjects/eco/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +7 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/shr/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.2/aapt dump xmltree /home/shr/AndroidStudioProjects/eco/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1c
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="9" (Raw: "9")
               A: package="com.example.eco" (Raw: "com.example.eco")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1c
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0x9
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1c
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: uses-permission (line=15)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=16)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" (Raw: "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")
               E: uses-permission (line=17)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" (Raw: "com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE")
               E: application (line=25)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="eco" (Raw: "eco")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=31)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.eco.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.example.eco.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=45)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: meta-data (line=55)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f040016
                   E: intent-filter (line=59)
                     E: action (line=60)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=62)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=69)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: service (line=73)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:directBootAware(0x01010505)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=77)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=80)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestoreRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestoreRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=83)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=86)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=89)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=92)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                   E: meta-data (line=95)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar")
                     A: android:value(0x01010024)="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar")
                 E: receiver (line=100)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: service (line=106)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: service (line=110)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" (Raw: "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")
                   A: android:enabled(0x0101000e)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: activity (line=116)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:excludeFromRecents(0x01010017)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 E: service (line=125)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 E: activity (line=130)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity")
                   A: android:permission(0x01010006)="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:excludeFromRecents(0x01010017)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: provider (line=138)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" (Raw: "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.example.eco.firebaseinitprovider" (Raw: "com.example.eco.firebaseinitprovider")
                   A: android:initOrder(0x0101001a)=(type 0x10)0x64
                 E: activity (line=144)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x01030010
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: meta-data (line=149)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.google.android.gms.version" (Raw: "com.google.android.gms.version")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=@0x7f060000
[   +5 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on Android SDK built for x86.
[        ] executing: /home/shr/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.example.eco
[  +39 ms] executing: /home/shr/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages com.example.eco
[ +256 ms] package:com.example.ecom2
           package:com.example.eco
[   +2 ms] executing: /home/shr/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell cat /data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.eco.sha1
[  +19 ms] 1ccaac39e064fba8814f6f0960d3215a68c8c049
[        ] Latest build already installed.
[        ] Android SDK built for x86 startApp
[   +4 ms] executing: /home/shr/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true --ez start-paused true com.example.eco/com.example.eco.MainActivity
[  +43 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.example.eco/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[        ] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
[ +661 ms] Observatory URL on device: http://127.0.0.1:37025/I74KvouTWb8=/
[   +1 ms] executing: /home/shr/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:0 tcp:37025
[   +7 ms] 37317
[        ] Forwarded host port 37317 to device port 37025 for Observatory
[   +5 ms] Caching compiled dill
[ +140 ms] Connecting to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:37317/I74KvouTWb8=/
[   +1 ms] DDS is currently disabled due to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62507
[ +192 ms] Successfully connected to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:37317/I74KvouTWb8=/
Waiting for Android SDK built for x86 to report its views...
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"c5f91b7c-12f5-4bf7-9a15-65269a624386","id":"1","progressId":null,"message":"Waiting for Android SDK built for x86 to report its views..."}}]
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"c5f91b7c-12f5-4bf7-9a15-65269a624386","id":"1","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
[  +17 ms] DevFS: Creating new filesystem on the device (null)
[  +27 ms] DevFS: Created new filesystem on the device (file:///data/user/0/com.example.eco/code_cache/ecoHZAWNP/eco/)
[   +3 ms] Updating assets
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:37317/I74KvouTWb8=/ws
[{"event":"app.debugPort","params":{"appId":"c5f91b7c-12f5-4bf7-9a15-65269a624386","port":37317,"wsUri":"ws://127.0.0.1:37317/I74KvouTWb8=/ws","baseUri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.eco/code_cache/ecoHZAWNP/eco/"}}]
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"c5f91b7c-12f5-4bf7-9a15-65269a624386","id":"2","progressId":null,"message":"Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86..."}}]
[ +145 ms] Scanning asset files
[   +3 ms] <- reset
[        ] Compiling dart to kernel with 0 updated files
[        ] <- recompile package:eco/main.dart 28868c49-6ac5-4a14-9af6-0e0d1deef50c
[        ] <- 28868c49-6ac5-4a14-9af6-0e0d1deef50c
[ +173 ms] Updating files
[ +264 ms] DevFS: Sync finished
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"c5f91b7c-12f5-4bf7-9a15-65269a624386","id":"2","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
[   +1 ms] Synced 4.2MB.
[        ] <- accept
[   +2 ms] Connected to _flutterView/0xab9bcc10.
[{"event":"app.started","params":{"appId":"c5f91b7c-12f5-4bf7-9a15-65269a624386"}}]
[ +634 ms] D/EGL_emulation( 8234): eglMakeCurrent: 0xab9b3580: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x91738150)
[{"id":0,"result":{"value":"android","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.platformOverride"}}]
[{"id":1,"result":{"timeDilation":"1.0","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.timeDilation"}}]
[{"id":2,"result":{"enabled":"false","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.debugPaint"}}]
[{"id":3,"result":{"enabled":"false","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.debugPaintBaselinesEnabled"}}]
[{"id":4,"result":{"enabled":"false","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.repaintRainbow"}}]
[{"id":5,"result":{"enabled":"false","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.showPerformanceOverlay"}}]
[{"id":6,"result":{"enabled":"true","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.debugAllowBanner"}}]
[{"id":7,"result":{"enabled":"false","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.inspector.structuredErrors"}}]
[{"id":8,"result":{"enabled":"true","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.inspector.structuredErrors"}}]
[{"id":9,"result":{"enabled":"false","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.inspector.show"}}]
[{"id":10,"result":{"enabled":"false","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.inspector.trackRebuildDirtyWidgets"}}]
[{"id":11,"result":{"enabled":"false","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.inspector.trackRebuildDirtyWidgets"}}]
[{"id":12,"result":{"enabled":"false","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.inspector.trackRepaintWidgets"}}]
[{"id":13,"result":{"enabled":"false","type":"_extensionType","method":"ext.flutter.inspector.trackRepaintWidgets"}}]
```

Here's a part of it, due to the limitation i'm unable to give the whole thing!
Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: could you elaborate on what doesn't work? What shows up on the screen?

Comment: Well, during the setting up the android project, after doing the steps and adding the jason folder to the correct directory , it should normally be synced and it would also be shown there with a green tick, but it's not..

Comment: hmm. are your firebase packages updated to their latest versions?

Comment: Yes, i copied the part instructed from the installing tab, those should be the latest version!